# Why is my Free/Busy Schedule only publishing 2 months of info when I have it configured for 6?

Tags: exchange-2003, public-folders

I'm using Exchange 2003 SP2 (I know, I need to upgrade this, but there are bureaucratic issues that need to be worked out first) and am having difficulties with the Free/Busy Schedule.  For some reason, it's defaulted to publishing only 2 months of Free/Busy info for users, even though my GPO has it set for 6 months, and my non-policy registry key is set for 6 months.

These are my non-policy registry keys:

```
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\preferences\fbpublishrange] = 6
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\preferences\fbupdatesecs] = 900
```

Note: this setting wasn't configured on one of my users' computers, so I added it, and it seemed to resolve the issue yesterday, but the view reverted to 2 months this morning, even though the setting persists.

These are my policy registry keys:

```
[HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0\outlook\preferences\fbpublishrange] = 6
[HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0\outlook\preferences\fbupdatesecs] = 900
```

The policy is managed by GPO and is being applied properly to my computer/user profile:

[image]

My exchange environment is made up of 4 back-end servers and 1 front-end server.  I'm explicitly managing all public folders (including the free-busy schedule) on 1 back-end server (meaning I have no mailboxes on this folder; I built it specifically for public folders to resolve an issue I was having with public folder replications).  All mailbox stores are configured by system policy to default to the 1 back-end server I designated for public folders.

I'm lead to believe this is a public folder issue, but I can't see how, since only 1 server is serving public folders, and there aren't any special permissions needed for the Free/Busy schedule.

Why would my free/busy schedule only publish 2 months of info when I have it configured for 6?  This is happening for all my users.

Answer (score 0):

Check that registry key on your Exchange Server: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Excdo\Parameters

Name: FBPublishMonth
Value type: DWORD
Value data: The period, in months, for which you want to publish Free/Busy information

There is a know error for that, check KB917687.

> You configure the published Free/Busy information for a mailbox to be
>   displayed for longer than the two months that is the default time
>   period in Microsoft Outlook. However, after some time, you see that
>   this information is displayed for only two months. This issue occurs
>   when you register the Auto Accept Agent to process meeting requests
>   for the affected mailbox.

Comment: The key didn't exist, so I manually created it.  I restarted IIS and System Attendant.  Going to refresh a few users' systems to see if things change.